# School for samurai

Tags: story-identification, anime

This is what I remember about the anime. Our main protagonist is a male and goes to a school which people are samurai or warriors. The anime starts with two factions/clubs from the school are fighting over something. Turns out our mc is not a super stronger person but someone that is great at strategy. Throughout the battle the other team is closing in on his team. But he has a brilliant plan using the river the other team's coordinator or captain that is at the river has fought there before and know the river is too deep to go across. Our main character in the end gets his people to pull up a bridge and rush the enemy that was not expecting that. At the end of the battle someone sister (white hair with an X scar) joins the battle on the other team's side and she is ones of the greats (people who have superhuman strength). Then someone join our main character side and it is a black-haired girl who is also one of the greats and one of the only ones that can fight this other great. At the end of the battle I believe that our mc won. He then goes back to his dorm that he lives in. He seems to be the only male out of 5 or more females (that in the end tend to like him even if they hide it).

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, what sort of time period was the story set in?

Comment: Last year or the year before is when I watched it. time period I would say more modern-day time period the school they attend is just very survival of the fittest ideals/ old fashioned.

Comment: Did you see this on a streaming service like Netflix or "normal" TV? Knowing that might make looking for it easier.

Comment: I honestly do not remember where I watched it sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The Answer: *Majikoi - Oh! Samurai Girls*

> In Kawakami City, having a samurai ancestor and 'fighting spirit' isn't just an interesting fact, it dictates how you're ranked on the social totem pole. Fortunately, that's something kids like Yamato Naoe have learned to deal with by forming into small 'bands,' (that's the samurai type, NOT music.) However, the delicate balance of Yamato's group is thrown off when two more girls join the group. —[IMDb](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt3416460/)

Comment: While it's great you managed to track down what you were looking for, it's a good idea to [add](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/278759/edit) in some matching details from the question into your answer. A brief description of the anime, or a synopsis would help. And don't forget to mark your answer as accepted in 24 hours time :)